# Replacing values in a dataframe, based on column names containing some characters

Tags: r, string, dplyr, replace

I have this dataset containing a number of columns starting with similar names

```
`CropType<-maize, beans,peas
NumberSM<-200,300,NA
PercentageSM<-90%,50%,NA
NumberLM<-600,NA,234
PercentageLM<-20%,NA,78%
df1<-data.frame(CropType,NumberSM,PercentageSM,NumberLM,PercentageLM)`
```

I would wish to request a single line of code that replaces any missing value in the column that starts with Number, with 0.0, and replaces any column missing any value in the column that starts with Percentage, with 0.0%.

My desired output is

```
`CropType<-maize, beans,peas
NumberSM<-200,300,0.0
PercentageSM<-90%,50%,0.0%
NumberLM<-600,0.0,234
PercentageLM<-20%,0.0%,78%
df1<-data.frame(CropType,NumberSM,PercentageSM,NumberLM,PercentageLM)`
```

I have tried this

```
`df1 %>%
  mutate(NumberLM=replace(NumberLM,is.na(NumberLM),0.0),
         PercentageLM=replace(PercentageLM,is.na(PercentageLM),'0.0%'))`
```

But I have several columns that need replacements, and I am avoiding referencing each column to replace

Comment: `?dplyr::across` and `?dplyr::starts_with` might be what you're after

Comment: Kindly, would you mind pointing to an example of how it works, or please use data frame example above to show the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way with `mutate/across`. See code comments for explanations.

```r
CropType <- c("maize", "beans", "peas")
NumberSM <- c(200,300,NA)
PercentageSM <- c("90%","50%",NA)
NumberLM <- c(600,NA,234)
PercentageLM <- c("20%",NA,"78%")
df1 <- data.frame(CropType,NumberSM,PercentageSM,NumberLM,PercentageLM)

library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

# here mutate all columns where is.numeric returns TRUE
df1 %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~replace(.x, is.na(.x), 0.0)))
#>   CropType NumberSM PercentageSM NumberLM PercentageLM
#> 1    maize      200          90%      600          20%
#> 2    beans      300          50%        0         <NA>
#> 3     peas        0         <NA>      234          78%

# to change the percentages, first determine which
# columns have a '%' in them, then a mutate/across 
# similar to the one above does the trick
i_perc <- sapply(df1, \(x) any(grepl("%", x)))

df1 %>%
  mutate(across(which(i_perc), ~ replace(.x, is.na(.x), "0.0%")))
#>   CropType NumberSM PercentageSM NumberLM PercentageLM
#> 1    maize      200          90%      600          20%
#> 2    beans      300          50%       NA         0.0%
#> 3     peas       NA         0.0%      234          78%
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-18 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>